# How to store multiple instance of a class object in a list in python?

Tags: python

1. How do I store multiple instances of a class objects in a list?
2. How do I bind a name to a type in Python? In Java, I would do something like this:

   ```
   SliceField[] schemaElements = {
       new SliceField("cust", SliceDB.INT),
       new SliceField("name", SliceDB.STRING),
       new SliceField("age", SliceDB.INT),
       new SliceField("phone", SliceDB.STRING),
       new SliceField("address", SliceDB.STRING)
   }
   ```

How would I do that in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 1), you just need a list.

```
schemaElements = [SliceField("cust", SliceDB.INT), ..., SliceField("address", SliceDB.STRING)]
```

Regarding 2), I am not exactly sure what you mean:

- Should you mean making sure that a variable always has a certain type, there is (a) no (easy) way to do that and (b) it is [discouraged (use Duck Typing instead)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).
- Should you mean renaming types (like C `typedef`), just assign them (`newName = typeName`)

Comment: instead of have SliceDB.INT, i just want it to be bind to Int because here i will not create a class name Slice.INT

Comment: So you just want to signal what type that field should have?

Comment: so will i have something like schemaElements=[SliceField("cust", int)...]?

Comment: Yes. Also, you can use that to automagically convert the values to the right type, because `int` and `str` are functions turning values into integers and strings respectively.

Comment: it is ok. fixed it. Thank you do much hlt

Comment: In my main class SliceField, i have i created a dictionary to store the each of those instance and i would like to use the first element of the dictionary as the key to my dictionary. when i do that and i want to check the value of my dictionary using the follwoing:for k,v in dictionary.items():
            print (k,v)    . i have cust which appear many time and it is separated with a space after the first character

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Python just as well as you can in Java:

```
 class Test:
     def __init__(self, a, b):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b

 l = [Test(1, 2), Test(3, 4), Test("I declare", "a thumb war")]

 l[0].a
 >>> 1

 l[2].b
 >>> 'a thumb war'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
schemaElements = [SliceField("cust", SliceDB.INT),....]
```

While doing so, make sure that the class `SliceField` has `__init__` defined.

```
class SliceField(value,type):
     def __init__(self, value, type):
         self.value = value
         self.type = type
     # Define other class parameters
```

If you want `SliceField` to bind to some particular conditions, you will have to define it inside you class itself.

Comment: how can i bind my instance variale to a type, i do not have the Slide.DB class?